# CakePHP3 error parsing database result set

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

In my controller i have:

```
public function index()
{
    $streams = $this->Streams->find('all')->where(['user_id'=>2]);

    echo $streams->count();
    die();
    $this->set('streams', $streams);
}
```

When I set a user_id that has results in databse, it works fine. But when I set a user_id with not results, when I tried to loop the query or even count the results, i get the following error:

InvalidArgumentException
Cannot convert value to bool

[image: cakephp3 database error]

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always include the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also elaborate on the context (for DB related problems for example, mention the DBMS, show the schema of the involed tables)!, and last but not least, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks! Often the problem solves itself when collecting such information.

Comment: Thanks @ndm, finally I solve that problem, it's was so tricky! In my database I has my user_id field as TINYINT, so when the user id was set to 1, it worked fine, but when other user_id, I think cakephp throw the "convert to boolean" exception